# Data Label only when mouse click on the xy cordinate

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Hi my questions is related to

[Labeling points in order in a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140312/labeling-points-in-order-in-a-plot)

and

[Data label on each entry in xy scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100398/data-label-on-each-entry-in-xy-scatter?lq=1)

but I would like to make the label visible only when the user clicks on the corresponding coordinate. My graph has a lot of points on the scatter plot(172) and hence infeasible to label all.

Thanks

Comment: An easy way might be to utilize the datacursormode and use user-defined update function. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11242506/1351522 and http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/datacursormode.html

Comment: @H.Muster Your pointer works...Thanks

Comment: Great! Why don't you post your working solution as an answer here (and accept it)? It might help other people.